# How to delete files owned by other users windows 7?

Tags: permissions

I have an external hard drive that I used to install programs on, I have since formatted my c drive and use the external drive as a storage only drive. There are however two remnants left over from the previous install on the external hd.

One is a folder full of Windows update files and the other is a Program files folder. I tried to delete the folder but it would give me the "need permissions" dialogue box and would then tell me I need permissions from user "S- ... #####". I did an ownership change on the folder and sub folders/files but that didn't work. Its still says I need permission from the new owner, even though I am the owner ... it does not make any sense. I cannot format the drive either as I have other files on it.

How can I force these folders to deletion?

Comment: Move your files from the external HDD, and then format the external HDD?

Comment: the files are on the external and I cannot do anything with them. I have edited the question

Comment: You need to do two things: 1) Take ownership so that you can change the permissions. (You already did this). 2) Change the permissions so that you (as in, your account) may read them. Your question seems to suggest that you only did the first part. If you did not just use `takeown` or did you also follow up with `icacls` ?

Comment: @hennes, yes that is what I missed, managed to delete the files. Can you put that in an answer and I will mark as correct?

Comment: I can, but I think the proper way is to get this closed as a duplicate. Else we end up with a lot of identical answers rather than a few very good ones. I am glad it solved things for you though.